# How to filter through 3 table joins using sequelize in expressjs api

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables named:

```js
//restaurants
columns ( id, name, restaurant_type_id(FK)
//restaurant_branches 
columns ( id, name, restaurant_id(FK)
//restaurant_types
columns ( id, restaurant_type_name('italian', 'french'...etc))
```

I would like to filter restaurant_branches by restaurant_type_id using query params in my restaurant_branches.findAll(); action in the controller as the following.

```js
const findAll = async (req, res) => {
    let RestaurantTypeId= req.query.restaurantType ? parseInt(req.query.restaurantType): null ;
    var type = RestaurantTypeId ? {where:{ restaurantTypeId: RestaurantTypeId }} : null ;
    console.log(RestaurantTypeId); 
    
    await RestaurantBranch.findAll({
        order: [
            ['id', 'ASC']
        ],

        include: 
        [
             {
                  model: Restaurant, 
                  type,
                  include: [{
                     model: RestaurantType,
                 }
                 ]
             }
                
            ]
    }).then((restaurantBranches) => {
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: "restaurant branches returned", 
            data: restaurantBranches
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {res.status(500).send(error.message);});

}
module.exports = {
    findAll
}
```

```
//Sequelize Associations
db.RestaurantType.hasMany(db.Restaurant);
db.Restaurant.belongsTo(db.RestaurantType);
// Restaurant / Restaurant Branches
db.RestaurantBranch.belongsTo(db.Restaurant);
db.Restaurant.hasMany(db.RestaurantBranch);
```

```
Sequelize log: 
Executing (default): SELECT "restaurant_branches"."id", "restaurant_branches"."name", "restaurant_branches"."description", "restaurant_branches"."email", "restaurant_branches"."phoneNumber", "restaurant_branches"."address", "restaurant_branches"."country_code", "restaurant_branches"."image", "restaurant_branches"."latitude", "restaurant_branches"."longitude", "restaurant_branches"."workingHours", "restaurant_branches"."workingDays", "restaurant_branches"."offDays", "restaurant_branches"."locationAddress", "restaurant_branches"."locationCity", "restaurant_branches"."status", "restaurant_branches"."hasParking", "restaurant_branches"."instruction", "restaurant_branches"."isActive", "restaurant_branches"."isDeleted", "restaurant_branches"."createdAt", "restaurant_branches"."updatedAt", "restaurant_branches"."restaurantId", "restaurant_branches"."cityId", "restaurant_branches"."districtId", "city"."id" AS "city.id", "city"."name" AS "city.name", "city"."code" AS "city.code", "city"."status" AS "city.status", "city"."isDeleted" AS "city.isDeleted", "city"."createdAt" AS "city.createdAt", "city"."updatedAt" AS "city.updatedAt", "city"."countryId" AS "city.countryId", "district"."id" AS "district.id", "district"."name" AS "district.name", "district"."isDeleted" AS "district.isDeleted", "district"."createdAt" AS "district.createdAt", "district"."updatedAt" AS "district.updatedAt", "district"."cityId" AS "district.cityId", "restaurant"."id" AS "restaurant.id", "restaurant"."name" AS "restaurant.name", "restaurant"."aboutUs" AS "restaurant.aboutUs", "restaurant"."phoneNumber" AS "restaurant.phoneNumber", "restaurant"."address" AS "restaurant.address", "restaurant"."latitude" AS "restaurant.latitude", "restaurant"."longitude" AS "restaurant.longitude", "restaurant"."image" AS "restaurant.image", "restaurant"."countryCode" AS "restaurant.countryCode", "restaurant"."restaurantRegisterDocument" AS "restaurant.restaurantRegisterDocument", "restaurant"."isDeleted" AS "restaurant.isDeleted", "restaurant"."createdAt" AS "restaurant.createdAt", "restaurant"."updatedAt" AS "restaurant.updatedAt", "restaurant"."restaurantTypeId" AS "restaurant.restaurantTypeId", "restaurant"."categoryId" AS "restaurant.categoryId", "restaurant"."userId" AS "restaurant.userId", "restaurant->restaurant_type"."id" AS "restaurant.restaurant_type.id", "restaurant->restaurant_type"."name" AS "restaurant.restaurant_type.name", "restaurant->restaurant_type"."photo" AS "restaurant.restaurant_type.photo", "restaurant->restaurant_type"."createdAt" AS "restaurant.restaurant_type.createdAt", "restaurant->restaurant_type"."updatedAt" AS "restaurant.restaurant_type.updatedAt" FROM "restaurant_branches" AS "restaurant_branches" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cities" AS "city" ON "restaurant_branches"."cityId" = "city"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "districts" AS "district" ON "restaurant_branches"."districtId" = "district"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "restaurants" AS "restaurant" ON "restaurant_branches"."restaurantId" = "restaurant"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "restaurant_types" AS "restaurant->restaurant_type" ON "restaurant"."restaurantTypeId" = "restaurant->restaurant_type"."id" ORDER BY "restaurant_branches"."id" ASC;
```

so far I'm doing this, and I get All the restaurant branches if I GET request to this URL:

`{{URL}}/restaurant_branches?restaurantType=2`

what I'd like to be getting instead is all the restaurant branches whom their restaurants belong to the restaurant type with id 2

Any help or guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you have associations in your Sequelize models for the tables? Also, also please enable tour Sequelize logging to see the full query in your console, so we can see what is wrong with the query.

Comment: @CyberEternal yes, I edited the question and added the sequelize associations. I'll go ahead and add the sequelize logging as well.

Comment: @CyberEternal I added the sequelize log for the query as well.

Comment: Ok. As I see the question already answered by Anatoly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You included `where` condition in `include` option as a `type` prop that's why it does not work as expected. You just need to indicate `where` either with your condition or as an empty object:

```js
var where = RestaurantTypeId ? { restaurantTypeId: RestaurantTypeId } : {} ;
    

include: 
        [
             {
                  model: Restaurant, 
                  where,
                  include: [{
                     model: RestaurantType,
                 }
                 ]
             }
                
            ]
```